# Replacing multiple lines with sed

Tags: sed

I have a situation where I want to replace multiple line text in a file using sed.
The search text is:

```
Enable=Yes
UseTest=No
UseTempS=No
UseStatic=No
IPAddress=
SubnetMask=
DefaultGateway=
```

And the text to be replaced is

```
Enable=No
UseTest=No
UseTempS=No
UseStatic=No
IPAddress=0.0.0.0
SubnetMask=255.255.255.0
DefaultGateway=1.1.1.1
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Basic sed replace command is `sed 's/input/output/g' file`. Give a try to that so we can help with problems you may face.

Comment: another option(if it suits your requirement) is, you remove the whole block from your file, and read the file content of your replacement. with `r`. that is, not line replacement, but block replacement. anyway, get your hands dirty is first step.

Comment: But how the text has new line in it.. How do I put the new line notation in the input and output, Taking this as input does not work Enable=Yes\nUseStatic=No\nUseTempS=No\nUseStaticWINS=No\nIPAddress=\nSubnetMask=\nDefaultGateway=

Comment: Do not try to replace whole block replace line by line.

Answer (score 4):

Code for GNU [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
sed -r 's#(.*)=(.*)#/\1=/s/=.*/=\2/#' file2|sed -f - file1
```

---

Session protocol:

```
$ cat file1
Enable=Yes
UseTest=No
UseTempS=No
UseStatic=No
IPAddress=
SubnetMask=
DefaultGateway=

$ cat file2
Enable=No
UseTest=No
UseTempS=No
UseStatic=No
IPAddress=0.0.0.0
SubnetMask=255.255.255.0
DefaultGateway=1.1.1.1

$ sed -r 's#(.*)=(.*)#/\1=/s/=.*/=\2/#' file2|sed -f - file1
Enable=No
UseTest=No
UseTempS=No
UseStatic=No
IPAddress=0.0.0.0
SubnetMask=255.255.255.0
DefaultGateway=1.1.1.1
```

Comment: Wow... You surely have style, sir.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match those fields in order, as you read them, one portable way:

```
sed -e   '/Enable=Yes/!b;N;
   /UseTest=No/!b;N;     
   /UseTempS=No/!b;N;    
   /UseStatic=No$/!b;N;  
   /IPAddress=$/!b;N;    
   /SubnetMask=$/!b;N;   
   /DefaultGateway=$/!b; 
   s/.*//;rtemplate' input
```

**template**

```
Enable=No
UseTest=No
UseTempS=No
UseStatic=No
IPAddress=0.0.0.0
SubnetMask=255.255.255.0
DefaultGateway=1.1.1.1
```

Comment: What is template here?

Comment: it is a file containing the replace text

Answer (score -1):

```
cat yourfile.txt | sed -f zarmacimamadzaghli.sed
```

**zarmacimamadzaghli.sed**

```
s/Enable=Yes/Enable=No/
s/UseTest=No/UseTest=No/
s/UseTempS=No/UseTempS=No/
s/UseStatic=No/UseStatic=No/
s/IPAddress=/IPAddress=0.0.0.0/
s/SubnetMask=/SubnetMask=255.255.255.0/
s/DefaultGateway=/DefaultGateway=1.1.1.1/
```

Comment: Sorry for my last comment. It is useful to change same text in many files. It could be done shorter with grouping, but it's fine.

Comment: @Birei Well, so what's a problem of doing this for several files?

Comment: No problem at all. My first thought was that the OP only wanted to do it once, so forget the comment deleted.